# worklight- Connection failure. Please check the server log for details

Tags: android, file-upload, console, connection, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight 6.1.*

I got the error when the file is uploading which already exits.

Error message is : "Connection failure. Please check the server log for details"
 [image]

Log message is :

```
> 11/2/16 17:27:58:060 KST] 00000223
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter          I
> FWLSE0217I: Responded to request with HTTP status 503: service
> unavailable - since server is currently
> deploying/undeploying/synchronizing artifacts to/from the db. [project
> FirstCredit] [11/2/16 17:28:10:557 KST] 0000003e
> com.worklight.gadgets.bean.WidgetServiceBean                 I
> FWLSE0085I: App 'FirstCredit-android-2.1.01' was deployed successfully
> on Worklight Server (the app version is 6.1.0.02.20160528-1310).
> [project FirstCredit]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen because you are trying to deploy a file (a .wlapp file perhaps?) while another upload is in progress. Wait a minute or two (depending on your internet connection) before attempting to upload again and see if the error returns or not.